# Cannot copy one file to another file

Tags: c

While im studying C from a old book (that might be the problem), i wrote the code to copy the content of one file to another one.
But somehow, the program stops working. I would appreciate some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;       //Pointers to the files
    int ch;

    if (argc!=3)    //Just checking if the user inserted the correct information
    {
        printf("\nCorrect mode: Program name, file1 -> file2 \n\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fin=fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if (fin==NULL)      //Checking if the file exists
    {
        printf("\n\nERROR!\n\nThe file you're trying to open does not exist or it cannot be opened.\n\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    if ((fout=fopen(argv[2], "wb"))==NULL)  // If it cannot create a file
    {
        printf("\n\nERROR!\n\nImpossible to create the file %s\n\n", argv[2]);
        exit(3);
    }

    while ((ch=fgetc(fin))!=EOF)
        fputs(ch, fout);

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `fputs` to write the characters.  It is used for strings (arrays of char).  Instead use `fputc`.

Comment: Ahw, i meant using fputc! Thanks mate

Comment: @DavidLopes please don't post the question before verifying your code.